# Keep user logged in for a while in Asp vb webform (visual studio 2015)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms, stay-logged-in

Please I want to ask a question,
I working on a project where users login before they can perform any action like comments, sharing of posts etc... I want the user to stay logged in for two weeks before the system can log him or her out..
I'm using visual studio 2015, I'm using the normal identity default login, how can I increase the login time in asp/VB webform

Comment: What do you mean by « normal identity default login »?

Comment: I'm using the default asp identity system to handle the user login (authentication / Authorization) (visual studio 2015)